# Parsing nested XML file

Tags: android, xml, parsing, nested

I have a XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD>
    <BaseURL>http://pilatus.d1.comp.nus.edu.sg/~a0095695/video_repo/</BaseURL>
    <SegmURL>
        <Low bandwidth="0">
            <Link>low/1.mp4</Link>
            <Link>low/2.mp4</Link>
            <Link>low/3.mp4</Link>
            <Link>low/4.mp4</Link>
            <Link>low/5.mp4</Link>
        </Low>
        <Medium bandwidth="1">
            <Link>med/1.mp4</Link>
            <Link>med/2.mp4</Link>
            <Link>med/3.mp4</Link>
            <Link>med/4.mp4</Link>
            <Link>med/5.mp4</Link>
        </Medium>
        <High bandwidth="2">
            <Link>hig/1.mp4</Link>
            <Link>hig/2.mp4</Link>
            <Link>hig/3.mp4</Link>
            <Link>hig/4.mp4</Link>
            <Link>hig/5.mp4</Link>  
        </High>
    </SegmURL>
</MPD>
```

Depending on the value of integer quality, i need to create a linkedlist of the corresponding link

so if quality=0, my linked list will contain low/1.mp4 to low/2.mp4

Gone through a lot of tutorials but they explain only for non nested xml files.

How to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: [see this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-xml-parsing-using-dom-parser.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your xml in my project using [XMLPull Parser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)(One of android xml parser, recommended by android on their site) and it traverse all the tags and print the content of all.

Try this, sample code is also given in the site, I also use it to solve your problem and got what you want..,.

Answer (score 0):

Please try dom4j, and use xpath to locate the corresponding the child node/nodes directly. And write loop to process all the values.